# Dart type Hints on Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, configuration

I am used to working with IntelliJ and Kotlin, now I am giving flutter a try with Android Studio (Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2) and Dart.

I was hoping to get the same feature of "type hinting" with Dart as I get with Kotlin on "regular IntelliJ" but I can't seem to find where to activate it.

Is this feature available for Android Studio and Dart? If so, where can I activate it?

Thanks in Advance.